# Remove the underline from mat-select (@angular/material 15.0.3)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use mat-select, but don't want the underline that comes with mat-select.

```
<mat-form-field 
  style="margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em"
  appearance="fill"
>
  <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2" disabled>Option 2 (disabled)</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

I tried to make underline display 'none' but it is not making any difference,

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
 }
```

and also tried to make appearance as 'none' but I get this error,

> Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'.ngtsc(2322)

```
<mat-form-field 
  style="margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em"
  appearance="none"
>
```

note: I am using "@angular/material": "^15.0.3".

Answer (score 0):

Use this to override bottom border:

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Tried this. But the result is still the same. Unable to remove the underline.

Answer (score 0):

The markup of the Angular Material components has changed with the latest update of version 15.

You can remove/hide the bottom line with this:

```css
div[matformfieldlineripple] {
      display: none;
}
```